# Building & Linking problems with Xcode3.2.3, iPhone SDK 4.0 and FlurryLib

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Architecture in build settings is "Standard"

> Undefined symbols:
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FlurryAPI", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref-to-FlurryAPI in xxxxAppDelegate.o
>         objc-class-ref-to-FlurryAPI in RegisterC.o
>         objc-class-ref-to-FlurryAPI in LoginC.o
>         objc-class-ref-to-FlurryAPI in FeedbackC.o
>         objc-class-ref-to-FlurryAPI in CreateAccountOp.o
>         objc-class-ref-to-FlurryAPI in CreateSessionOp.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Well - so they say persistance pays.

I was plagued by this error for hours and hours.

So here is what I did,

1. Register and Download the API again from FlurryLib
2. Remove all existing traces i.e. folders in the Applications directory
3. Add to the API again to the project
4. Clean all targets
5. Build and Run in the simulator.

It works !